# What is a better practice for initializing class members?

Tags: c++, c++17

Let's assume I have a class A looking like that:

```
class A {
public:
  public A(bool someFlag, Params someParams);
private:
  vector<string> texts;
}
```

I would like to extract the logic of initializing the `texts` member field.
I came up with 2 ideas:

1. First idea - static, private member functions that would **return** the desired vectors of texts.

   ```
   A::A(bool someFlag, Params someParams) {
     if (someFlag)
       texts = createSomeTexts(someParams);
     else
       texts = createOtherTexts(someParams);
   }
   ```
2. Second idea - private member functions that would assign the desired vectors of texts to the class members **by themselves**.

   ```
   A::A(bool someFlag, Params someParams) {
     if (someFlag)
       createAndAssignSomeTexts(someParams);
     else
       createAndAssignOtherTexts(someParams);
   }
   ```

Of course both versions do the job correctly, but I wonder what is the advised approach to theese situations. Also, if the approach should change if member initalization requires more parameters (especially ones that are stored in the class as members as well).

Comment: You could even do `A::A(bool someFlag, Params someParams): texts(someFlag ? createSomeTexts(someParams) : createOtherTexts(someParams)) { }` turning it into a member initialization. (The `create`... functions should be freestanding or `static` member functions in this case.) Which one to prefer? I'm afraid this is a matter of taste...

Comment: Generally, initialisation of a class member is expected to be in constructors, but not all constructors need to be explicitly defined (e.g. copy constructor can be defined implicitly by the compiler).   Can you clarify how many constructors you need to implement (e.g. if the initialisation logic is teased out into another function, how many constructors would specifically call that function?) and where else (e.g. in what code) that function will be called?

Comment: When I've to implement multiple constructors with different signatures which does actually rather the same, I used a private `init()` function doc.ed as "shared initialization" which I called in the body of every related constructor. Meanwhile, with C++11, constructors may call each other. - This is even more elegant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should strive to initialize your data member, not assign to them in the constructor body. Both versions you showed cause default construction of the `std::vector<std::string>` instance, and assign to it later. Hence, I'd suggest this:

```
A::A(bool someFlag, const Params& someParams) :
    texts(someFlag ? createSomeTexts(someParams) : createOtherTexts(someParams))
{}
```

or, more readable, let `createSomeTexts` handle the flag, too:

```
A::A(bool someFlag, const Params& someParams) :
    texts(createSomeTexts(someFlag, someParams))
{}
```

Make `createSomeTexts` a member function if it needs to access other data members (make sure they're declared before the `texts` member and properly initialized - as @Scheff pointed out, this is unlikely to be a good idea, though). Otherwise, make it a free function (see [here](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsu/184401197) why this is preferrable). Once `createSomeTexts` is a free function, you could equally well construct the object like this:

```
std::vector<std::string> stringsToInject = createSomeText(/* Some flags.... */);

A instance(stringsToInject); // A's ctor updated to make this work
```

which could further separate concerns as the constructor of `A` takes care of initializing the data members, while the logic to create the initialization data is located somewhere else.

Comment: A member function which is called in constructor but accesses other members... This doesn't sound like a good idea. (Rather like a design to shoot in your own foot ealier or later.) ;-)

Comment: @Scheff I agree, it's probably not a good idea... technically possible though. I'll add a note, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Yeah it's technically possible as the construction order of members is well defined. But it's very fragile considering that code is written by humans which overlook things and get lost in code quantity sometimes... ;-)

Comment: I think that if `createSomeTexts` is a free function, it should be in the anonymous namespace in the `.cpp` file. It is an implementation detail and shouldn't be exposed and you don't want it to cause name conflicts.

Comment: @ChrisDrew The drawback would be  that you can't write a unit test for this function. And if there is a certain logic necessary to be handled by a separate helper function, it's worth testing it in isolation. I would put it into a separate file, e.g. `myclassdetail.h/.cpp` such that it's "implementation-detail-ness" becomes obvious.

Answer (score 2):

I would use case 1 because the functions createSomeTexts and createOtherTexts do not alter any class variables. That means these functions can be unit tested.

It is better not to use global variables and if you must, not to alter them from the global scope (this->) but to pass them by reference or as a pointer to your function.
This way you can pass stubs in your code and write test cases.

Also, Params should be a const reference:

```
class A {
  public:
    public A(const bool someFlag, const Params &someParams);
private:
  vector<string> texts;
}
```

Comment: Although I marked the other answer as the most helpful, I really like the testabitlity aspect of your comment, I haven't even thought of this, thanks!